# How do I import VisualBasic.MyServices in a Console Application?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I am creating a `Console Application` in `Visual Basic`. I would like to use features like `My.Computer.FileSystem` like I would in `Windows Forms` but it is unreferenced in my project.

After a bit of googling, I came across [this namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.myservices?view=netframework-4.8) called `Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices` which appears to contain things like `FileSystem` which I am unable to access with my `Console Application`

I have tried referencing a few different libraries that I found in `COM Components`, but none appear to include `MyServices`

I know this is possible because I used to be able to do this when I worked with `Console Applications` a few years ago.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: My guess would be that your project is targeting .NET Core rather than .NET Framework and `My` is not supported on .NET Core.

Comment: What exactly did you want to use `My.Computer.FileSystem` for? Some of it can be easily replaced with functionality from `System.IO` or perhaps elsewhere.

Comment: It appears that I am targeting the wrong thing, I wanted to use `FileSystem` because I find it much more straight-forward and tidy which _i think we all_ prefer and I wasn't going to resort to `System.IO` if it was something simple which I hadn't missed. Thank you so much @jmcilhinney

Comment: Each person has their own preferences but I would dispute that for things that they can both do, e.g. using `File.Exists` rather than `My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested to confirm and, using VS 2019, the `My` namespace is supported as usual in a VB Console Application project targeting .NET Framework 4.8 but it is not supported in a similar project targeting .NET Core 3.1. I'm not sure what the situation will be in .NET 5 but, for now, stick with .NET Framework or forgo the `My` namespace.

Comment: That makes more sense to me, thank you so much for your help :)